# Structuremap all instances of abstract

Tags: c#, structuremap, structuremap3

Using Net 4.5.1 and StructureMap 3.1.4

I have services that extending an abstract class:

```
 public abstract class Charting<T> {

   protected readonly String baseConfigurationString;

   public Charting(String baseConfigurationString)
   {
      this.baseConfigurationString = baseConfigurationString;
   }

   ...
 }
```

For every concrete service I want to set the **baseConfigurationString**.  Right now I am doing it individually per service:

```
 public class MyRegistry : Registry
 {
    public MyRegistry()
    {
        Profile("Development", x => {
            ForConcreteType<AveragePartySizeChart>().Configure.Ctor<String>("baseConfigurationString").Is(MyDbConfiguration.getBaseConnectionString());

            ...next service....about 6 total
        });
    }
 }
```

Is there anyway to do this generally acting against the abstract class despite it having a generic qualifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion, and what we did with StructureMap for configuration within FubuMVC, is to create a class something like:

```
public class ConnectionSettings
{
    public string Connection {get;set;}
}
```

and resolve that through StructureMap as a singleton. Then in any class that needs the connection string, just do:

```
public abstract class DatabaseConnectionUser
{
    public DatabaseConnectionUser(ConnectionSettings settings){}
}
```

Autowiring will connect your `ConnectionSettings` object to all the class objects that take in
that object in their constructor function.

You *could* try using a custom `IPluginGraphConfiguration` class in StructureMap 3 to set the ctor argument explicitly on all Instance's that build a subclass, but I think that would be more work.

Comment: @Jermey, Thanks.  I did as KevM suggested and Weinart making a custom settings object that I pass to the **Charting** abstraction.  Works great.  Appreciate the tip on SM graphs and I looked at the FubuMVC code.

Answer (score 1):

This does not solve your abstract constructor argument setting via Profile problem but I would like to suggest that you avoid taking dependencies on primitive types like `System.String` and use an abstraction instead.

You could have an type `IDatabaseSettings` which gets the connection settings you desire for either environment variables or application settings.

```
public interface IDatabaseSettings
{
  string DbConnectionString { get; set; }
}

public class DatabaseSettings : IDatabaseSettings
{
  public string DbConnectionString { get; set; }
}

public class DatabaseRegistry : Registry
{
  public DatabaseRegistry()
  {
    For<IDatabaseSettings>().Use(c =>
    {
        var setting = c.GetInstance<DatabaseSettings>();

        setting.DbConnectionString =
            System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseSettings.DBConnectionString"];

        return setting;
    });
  }
}
```

**Important:** Your project will need to reference System.Configuration.

If you have a lot of settings you may want to conventionalize this pattern. We use the `SettingsProvider` out of [FubuCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FubuCore/) to make this a breeze. You simply have objects that end in Settings which get their properties automatically populated out of application settings. Chad Myers has [a nice blog post on it](http://lostechies.com/chadmyers/2011/06/03/cool-stuff-in-fubucore-no-5-easy-configuration/).

Comment: Thanks for the tip on avoiding primitive types and the link to FubuCore.